# Batch script to count each string in list of file

Tags: batch-file

I have text file which contains a list of employee codes one below the other:

```
KUMAA286
KUMAA286
MATCHS02
GANNAS
MATCHS02
GANNAS
```

I want a batch script which can give me a count each of the employee code in one `output.txt` file.

E. g.:

```
The number of KUMAA286 is 2
The number of MATCHS02 is 2
The number of GANNAS is 2
```

Comment: You should show your own coding effort, [SO] isn't a script writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Read the strings and count each one on its corresponding array element
for /F %%a in (input.txt) do set /A "count[%%a]+=1"

rem Show the results
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do echo The number of %%a is %%b
```

Comment: Agreed, even if an initialize is missing. Even simpler an off topic Powershell one liner: `gc .\Employees.txt|group|%{"The number of {0} is {1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Count}`

Answer (score 0):

Contradicting myself ;-)
You have to sort your list prior comparing each entry with the previous one
and if the same count up.
If not the same output count and last entry.

To have different counts, this changed list:

```
KUMAA286
GANNAS
KUMAA286
MATCHS02
GANNAS
GANNAS
```

And this batch

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Cnt=-1
Set Last=n/a
For /f %%A in (' Sort Employees.txt') Do (
  if %%A neq !Last! (
    if !Cnt! geq 1 Echo The number of !Last! is !Cnt!
    Set Cnt=1
    Set Last=%%A
  ) Else (
    Set /A Cnt+=1
  )
)
If %Cnt% geq 1 Echo The number of !Last! is !Cnt!
```

Will return:

```
The number of GANNAS is 3
The number of KUMAA286 is 2
The number of MATCHS02 is 1
```

Comment: I am trying to understand , Can you explain what is Set Last=n/a , what is n/a

Comment: It's just to have the var defined with any content. Otherwise the first if would have an invalid comparison when `!Last!` evaluates to nothing in the very first line. `n/a` usually stands for not available..